# Android Play Store - How to offer free copies of paid app

Tags: android, google-play

CONTEXT: I have a free and a paid version of an app on the play store. I would like to offer free copies of the paid version through post contests in various message boards
(ie: I would post in X forum: MY APP - SALES PITCH - FIRST 5 POSTERS GET FREE COPY OF PAID VERSION!)

Anyone know if (and how) this can be done?

Thanks!

LW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make both of your app in one free app and let the user purchase a license key to upgrade to the full version.

In this case you can give 5 keys for free.

Comment: I will look into how much trouble it would be to convert my current setup (two separate apps) into what you are describing. I like this idea a lot!

Comment: Ok, I think with this idea you can promote your app nicely. For this it also cant be copied without purchasing :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that you can give out FREE copies of a PAID app. One thing you can do is let the person purchase the app and then offer them a refund. Or you could just distribute the apk through email or thumb drive. In either case you will have to do the entire process again if there is an update to your paid app

Comment: I was actually thinking of sending the refund through through another means than the Play Store refund method, upon presentation of a sales receipt for the app (to avoid the tedious process of repeating the refund/dl sequence at each update...) - I guess this answers my question though, Ill give it a few just in case, and then I will mark this as answered. Thanks for the swift reply!

Comment: Please accept and upvote for the benefit of others if it helped you. Cheers

Comment: Isn't Google's transaction fee 30%? So if you sell for $1 you get 70c. If you then refund outside of the Play Store, you have to cough up the whole $1 yourself so are out of pocket by 30c. Just food for thought and probably not a big deal if the volume is low.

Comment: Yep that is true. Google charges 30 % of the transaction. But considering the question thats the only way that i know of